# Failed to render sass to css at newBuild error

Tags: android, css, ionic-framework, sass, ionic3

[image]

I am getting below error while building my ionic project. Please help me out in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting implies that the value you are passing to the function is not a valid colour. Check that you are passing a valid colour first.